# Check db table field (datetime) if it's empty or not

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, mysqli

After successful user registration my MySQL db table puts `0000-00-00 00:00:00` into `lastlogin_date` and `lastlogout_date` fields by default. type of both fields is `datetime`. In my php code i'm checking if user enters to the site for the first time

```
$lastlogin = $db->query("SELECT `lastlogin_date` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$_SESSION[id]'");
    $row = $lastlogin->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $lastlogin=$row['lastlogin_date'];
    if(empty($lastlogin))
    { do something}
```

But, seems, empty doesnt work in this case. how to check if the `lastlogin_date` field is empty or not?  if($lastlogin=='0000-00-00 00:00:00')??

Comment: `if ($lastlogin == '0000-00-00 00:00:00')` is not a bad option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0000-00-00 00:00:00` is a value. If you don't want to put any value, you should store `NULL`, which would make much more sense. NULL is the *lack* of value.

That being said, I think the best way is to select a boolean instead of your column :

```
-- (lastlogin_date is NULL) if you change your table structure
SELECT (lastlogin_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') as has_logged_in
  FROM users
 WHERE id = ?;
```

When you fetch your query, you can use `$row['has_logged_in']`, which is a boolean.

Comment: i heard that "null" is buggy. better to use empty string or default "0" but actually i don't understand the difference between them and pros cons

Comment: How is NULL buggy? That's a complete non sense. NULL only takes 1 _bit_ while a value can take up to several bytes, and NULL is the lack of value, as I said. Using an arbitrary value can also makes queries like `SELECT COUNT(some_col)` totally wrong. There's no point to use a value instead of NULL when the latter is more appropriated.

Comment: Where in the world did you hear that NULL is buggy? lol! I'd be really interested in hearing more about that. :) As @Vincent points out, NULL indicates "no value". How can that be _buggy_?